# CustomObjectTranslation person account record type

Tags: translation, package.xml, translation-workbench

I want to retrieve translations for person account record types from workbench.

I created a package.xml file which I uploaded to workbench via retrieve

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>Account-de</members>
        <name>CustomObjectTranslation</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>Account</members>
        <name>CustomObject</name>
    </types>
    <version>44.0</version>
</Package>
```

and I received record type translations, but only for standard accounts, not for person acconts.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CustomObjectTranslation xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">

 <recordTypes>
        <description><!-- Account record type for Austria --></description>
        <label>AT Organisation</label>
        <name>CORE_AT_Organization</name>
 </recordTypes>
```

Although person account record type is special type of account, it should be listed here. When I use SOQL in workbench

```
SELECT Name,IsPersonType,SobjectType FROM RecordType WHERE SobjectType = 'Account'
```

there is only one difference between standard account record type and person account record type in IsPersonType = True.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of trial and error, I have managed to retrieve the Person Account Record type translations through ANT. Please check [this post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/257438/migrate-standard-help-text-translations-and-person-account-translations-through/258628#258628) for the package.xml sample.