# Migrate Standard Help Text translations and Person Account Translations through ANT

Tags: migration, person-accounts, translation, helptext

I need an automated way to migrate the Help Text translations for standard fields and Person Account Record Type translations from a source org to a series of destination orgs(800+). I am not able to retrieve the metadata for this through the IDE, so not sure how could I achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error, I have managed to retrieve the Person Account Record Type translations through ANT. Here is how package.xml looks like in order to achieve this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>Account</members>
        <name>CustomObject</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>PersonAccount.PersonAccountBusiness</members>
        <name>RecordType</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>PersonAccount-de</members>
        <name>CustomObjectTranslation</name>
    </types>
    <version>45.0</version>
</Package>
```

It seems like if the Person Account record type name is not mentioned explicitly, its corresponding translation is not retrieved(unlike the other objects).

Also, it seems like the Standard Help Text Translation retrieval is not possible at this point through ANT. I have created [an Idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A0000003d3yQAA) for this, maybe it's going to be implemented in the future.